# HTML anchor jumps to id then top of page

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, permalinks

On [this page](http://nonestdeus.com/quotes/index.php#twain), I've used anchors to create permalinks to specific quotes on the page.

However, I've noticed when putting the url with the anchor directly into the browser's address bar, the page navigates to the anchor and then jumps to the top of the page.

What could be causing the page to jump to the top of the page after jumping to the anchor?

```
<a href="index.php#twain" id="twain" class="quote">Mark Twain</a>
```

When clicking on that link from the page, all is fine. However, when I type the URL directly into the browser, it jumps to the top of the page.

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/PenumbraBrah/pen/vKLymj

EDIT:
Okay. I think I found a temporary (or maybe long term solution).

If I add this script to the page:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    window.location.hash = "#" + hash;
  }
</script>
```

...then the page will be repositioned, even if it does jump to the top. It's a workaround at least.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code/markup/etc. related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: Aside from the fact that there is no in-question code, I think this is a good question. The error on the OP's page is odd, and I too would like to know the reason for its occurrence. I'll attempt to edit it and make it more fitting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll see if I can replicate it in an example that could be posted in a codepen, etc.

Comment: I am not experiencing what you're describing when visiting the page you linked. If you've fixed the issue then this question is a perfect example of why you should not link directly to the site you are having issues with, but rather recreate it so that others who may find this question in the future won't be confused as to why they are not seeing the issue you are reporting.

Comment: The thing is, you're linking to another file (index.php) and then to the anchor on that page ( #twain) so it will load the document (starting from the top) and once loaded, will jump to the anchor. The doc doesn't know index.php is the current file, so it will open it. Change your anchors to just `<a href="#twain" id="twain" class="quote">Mark Twain</a>`